# how to identify process which blocks suspend/hibernate

Tags: power-management, suspend

I have an intermittent problem with a laptop that doesn't sleep/hibernate after lid is closed. And I have no idea why.

I suspect that some process blocks sleeping/hibernating.

How can I identify that process so I can:

- kill it
- maybe do something with it, set something in options, etc...

Comment: look through `dmesg`.